# Rails - How to update a single attribute in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to rails and trying to achieve a simple task. I want to toggle a boolean attribute "done" on an image click.
In my view, my link looks like:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("done.png"),
    feed_item,
    :controller => :calendars, :action=>:toggle_done,:id=> feed_item.id,
    :title => "Mark as done", :remote=> true, :class=>"delete-icon" %>
```

I added a route as follows:

```
resources :calendars do
    get 'toggle_done', :on => :member
end
```

in the controller, I have created a method:

```
def toggle_done
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    toggle = !@calendar.done
@calendar.update_attributes(:done => toggle)

respond_to do |format|
  flash[:success] = "Calendar updated"
  format.html { redirect_to root_path }
  format.js
end
```

When I click on the image, nothing happens I see the following error:

```
Started GET "/toggle_done" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-12-27 13:56:38 +0530
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/toggle_done"):
```

I am sure there is something very trivial I am missing here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just FYI, ActiveRecord provides "toggle" and "toggle!" methods to do exactly as the name claims on a given attribute.

Route ->

```
resources :calendars do
  member do
    put :toggle_done
  end
end
```

View (ensure you're using the correct route path and the correct HTTP Verb). GET should not be used for changing the database as per RESTful architecture. ->

```
<%= link_to image_tag("done.png"), feed_item, toggle_done_calendars_path(feed_item)
    :title => "Mark as done", :remote=> true, :class=>"delete-icon", :method => :put %>
```

Controller ->

```
def toggle_done
  @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
  @calendar.toggle!(:done)

  respond_to do |format|
    flash[:success] = "Calendar updated"
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: Aditya, damn..I never knew this :) thanks a ton. Again a request to share some good book or reference to Rails.

Comment: Actually in this case PUT should not be used either in the context of 'RESTful architecture' As GET, PUT, and DELETE all require indempotence, in that calling the action with parameters should return the same result everytime. Therefore a toggle will not really be RESTful unless you have a corresponding PUT and DELETE, or two PUTs one for each state (true / false).

Answer (score 2):

When using `link_to`, you can specify the URL by passing either an Active Record model with an associated resource, or by passing regular `:controller`/`:action` arguments. Now you're passing both an Active Record model (`feed_item`) and `:controller`/`:action` arguments, but you only should pass `:controller`/`:action` arguments in this case.

Also, when you pass both a URL hash and additional HTML arguments you need to include the brackets around the two hashes in order to distinguish between them.

Thus, try the following:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("done.png"),
    { :controller => :calendars, :action =>:toggle_done, :id => feed_item.id },
    { :title => "Mark as done", :remote => true, :class =>"delete-icon" } %>
```

Comment: Please use the path helpers to generate the route to this action.

Comment: This solution worked. I would really appreciate if you can point me to a comprehensive book/resources to rails. I find most of the books that build shopping carts really not up to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick steps to fix your problem is to move the :controller and :action out of the link_to method and into the route, and fix your route.

Your route is inside the block for resource :calendars. Every route in there will match on the /calendars/ path, so this route won't match /toggle_done. Here's a simple route that will match and route /toggle_done to :controller => :calendars, :action => :toggle_done

```
match :toggle_done => "calendars#toggle_done"
```

Having said that, I would suggest going with a RESTful route. I'm guessing you have calendar resources, which have many feed_items, and I'm guessing the toggle_done action updates the done boolean on one of these feed_items. An update should be mapped as a PUT request.

```
resources :calendars do
  resources :feed_items do
    put :toggle_done, :on => member
  end
end
```

This will give you a route for /calendars/1/feed_items/2/toggle_done, to toggle done on feed_item 2 in calendar 1.