# Undefined method when updating boolean in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to follow along with an answer posted here on Stackoverflow in order to update a boolean value in my app's database when an image is clicked ([Rails - How to update a single attribute in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537480/rails-how-to-update-a-single-attribute-in-controller)).

However, I'm getting the following error when I load the page that contains the image:

undefined method `toggle_is_contribution_comments_path' for #<#:0x000000053d8150>

My route file:

```
resources :comments do
    member do
      put :toggle_is_contribution
    end
    end
```

controller:

```
def toggle_is_contribution
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:work_id])
    @comment.toggle!(:is_contribution)

     respond_to do |format|
    flash[:success] = "Work updated"
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
  end
```

view:

```
<%= image_tag comment.user.photo.url(:avatar) %></span>&nbsp; <%= link_to comment.user.full_name, comment.user if comment.user %>
                                                <% if current_user == @work.user %>
                            <span class = "contribution">
                            <%= link_to image_tag("/assets/list_star.png"), comment, toggle_is_contribution_comments_path(comment),
                            :size => "15x15", :align => "right", :title=> "Add contribution to your work", :method=> :put %>
                            </span>
                        <% end %>
```

Why doesn't the app recognize the method? What did I do wrong? I checked my model and attr_accessible does include is_contribution

Thanks!
-b

EDIT 1: Rake routes:

```
toggle_is_contribution_comment PUT    /comments/:id/toggle_is_contribution(.:format) comments#toggle_is_contribution
                      comments GET    /comments(.:format)                            comments#index
                               POST   /comments(.:format)                            comments#create
                   new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)                        comments#new
                  edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                   comments#edit
                       comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                        comments#show
                               PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                        comments#update
                               DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                        comments#destroy
```

EDIT 2:

After editing the method name to Mischa's answer below I get a stringify keys error:

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/comments/1/toggle_is_contribution":String

EDIT 3:

Fixed the link_to but now I get this undefined error:

undefined method `toggle_is_contribution_comments_path' for #<#:0x00000004438ba0>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the path and I still get the same error. I just posted the relevant part of rake routes above (output was very large so I only added the part I think we need to see).

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the extra help. It happens on the view page around line 48 but I'm starting to think the issue lies in the works controller (a comment belongs_to a work; think comments on a blog). I updated the question with the Work controller

Comment: No. Your `link_to` is wrong. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
toggle_is_contribution_comment_path(comment)
```

Just stick `_path` to what you see in the first column of the output of `rake routes`.

Also, your [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is wrong. Instead of:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/list_star.png"), comment, toggle_is_contribution_comment_path(comment), etc.
```

do:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/list_star.png"), toggle_is_contribution_comment_path(comment), etc.
```

Note that the second argument to `link_to` is the url. So you don't need `comment` here. Passing `toggle_is_contribution_comment_path(comment)` as the second argument is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think this should work but now I'm getting a stringify keys error: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/comments/1/toggle_is_contribution":String

Comment: I changed the link_to and now I'm no longer getting stringify keys error. I'm getting undefined method `toggle_is_contribution_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000045101b8>:0x00000004438ba0>

Comment: @bruce Oh sorry.. obviously that should be `toggle_is_contribution_comment_path`... I copied the code from your question. Updated my answer again.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! You've been such a huge help. Thank you for sticking around a little longer and being patient. I've learned so much from you today.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. I added a little bit of extra explanation and a link to the API for `link_to`.